Ensuring consistent growth rate after domain transformation
I have the following function:
$f(x)=-\frac{2 \text{li}(x)}{3}$

As you can see, I´m interested in the range $x=[0,1]$, where its domain goes from $0$ to infinity with a certain growth rate.
My goal is to make a transformation to this function so that its new domain $D(f2(x))$ ranges from $0$ to a certain real value $k>0$, instead of $\infty$. I have tried with $f2(x)=\frac {k*f(x)}{1+f(x)}$ resulting in the following graph for $k=10$:

It seems to work, but I need to know if the growth rate of both $f(x)$ and $f2(x)$ are the same within their domains. Also, it would be a good solution to prove that $f2(x)$ is the best transformation available to preserve that rate.
